# Projection of the intersection of the graph of a function with a compact set

Tags: general-topology

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ be open, $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $p: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$defined by $p(x,y)=x$.

Let $M:=\{(x,y)| x \in \Omega, y=f(x)\}$ and suppose that $K \subseteq \Omega \times \mathbb{R}$ is compact.

> Is it true that $\overline{p(M\cap K)}\subseteq \Omega$?

I tried the following approach: let $g: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g(x,y)=y-f(x)$. We have that $M=g^{-1}(\{0\})$, so $M$ is closed **relatively to** $\Omega$. Since $K$ is compact then $K\cap M$ is compact and as $p$ is continuous $p(M\cap K)$ is compact too.

Since $p(M\cap K) \subseteq V$ and $p(M\cap K)$ is closed, then $\overline{p(M\cap K)}=p(M\cap K)\subseteq \Omega$.

The problem is with the relatively closed, hence I'm not sure I can affirm that $M\cap K$ is closed in the first place (it is definitely bounded though).

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $p(M\cap K)\subseteq p(K)\subseteq p(\Omega \times \mathbb{R})=\Omega$. But since $p(K)$ is closed, since $K$ is compact and $p$ is continuous, we actually have $\overline{p(M\cap K)}\subseteq p(K)$. Hence $\overline{p(M\cap K)}\subseteq \Omega$.